# Automatically install/uninstall an application from within another application

Tags: android

I am developing an Android device management service.

One of the functions for this is specifying what apps should be installed on registered devices of the service.

The scenario is that a manager will upload an enterprise app to the service for use on his employees' Android devices.

He then asks the service to deploy the app. The service communicates with a pre-installed app on the devices. This app downloads the enterprise app then installs it without any confirmation from the user.

Another requirement of this is that the user is prevented from installing or un-installing applications themselves.

I have been looking at the android.app.admin package but the policy functionality seems limited. I have also discovered that it is possible to donwnload an APK then fire an intent to install it. However this needs confirmation from the user.

In short, is it possible to install an Android application from within another application without any confirmation from the user whatsoever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Actually, Android is designed to *prevent* the scenario you're describing.  Bunching together several of your bullet points:
* Apps are installed without user interaction
* These apps are chosen not by the device user, but by a remote "manager"
* User has no ability to uninstall said apps
* User has no ability to install any other apps

There's no technical difference between this and malware.

However, there *is* an alternative, called [Google Apps Device Policy for Android](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190930), which allows the Administrator to (from the page):

> > Require that you have a PIN or password on your device.
> >     Require a complex password on your device. 
> >     Require a screen lock for idle timeout on your mobile device. 
> >     Wipe a lost or stolen device.
> >     Additionally, this application gives you the ability to remotely:
> >     Reset PIN
> >     Ring Device
> >     Lock Device
> >     Locate your device

It also has facilities for remote wiping a device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't expecting an engineer from Google! This is a project which I have to develop myself so I can't use a 3rd party application. Since managing applications is out of the question I'll scrap that idea and stick to implementing the same features that the Google Apps Device Policy for Android provides.

Comment: If this is the case how come, lot of companies creating MDM apps to manage the devices used in a company like air-watch, SOTI etc.